# How to defeat gzip (or other lossless compression)

Tags: compression, gzip

By pigeonhole principle, every lossless compression algorithm can be "defeated", i.e. for some inputs it produces outputs which are longer than the input. Is it possible to explicitly construct a file which, when fed to e.g. gzip or other lossless compression program, will lead to (much) larger output? (or, betters still, a file which inflates ad infinitum upon subsequent compressions?)

Comment: I'd expect most compression algorithms to be smart enough to not compress at all if they were going to make things worse.  They might add a constant number of bytes in headers, but producing a file 50% larger when you can just store the original bytes would be a pretty serious bug.

Comment: Your "proof" that a lossless compression scheme must be defeatable has a small flaw: there are actually n holes for n birds.  So a "compression" scheme that deflates any input by 0% and adds no headers will not be defeatable :-).

Comment: *"file which, when fed to e.g. gzip or other lossless compression program, will lead to (much) larger output?"* Well, you could do `cat /dev/urandom|gzip > ~/1.bin` on Linux....

Answer (score 8):

Well, I'd assume eventually it'll max out since the bit patterns will repeat, but I just did:

```
touch file
gzip file -c > file.1
...
gzip file.9 -c > file.10
```

And got:

```
  0 bytes: file
 25 bytes: file.1
 45 bytes: file.2
 73 bytes: file.3
103 bytes: file.4
122 bytes: file.5
152 bytes: file.6
175 bytes: file.7
205 bytes: file.8
232 bytes: file.9
262 bytes: file.10
```

Here are 24,380 files graphically (this is *really* surprising to me, actually):

[alt text http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~schultzm/images/filesize.png](http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~schultzm/images/filesize.png)

I was not expecting that kind of growth, I would just expect linear growth since it should just be encapsulating the existing data in a header with a dictionary of patterns.  I intended to run through 1,000,000 files, but my system ran out of disk space way before that.

If you want to reproduce, here is the bash script to generate the files:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch file.0

for ((i=0; i < 20000; i++)); do
    gzip file.$i -c > file.$(($i+1))
done

wc -c file.* | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' | sed 's/file.//' | sort -n > filesizes.txt
```

The resulting filesizes.txt is a tab-delimited, sorted file for your favorite graphing utility.  (You'll have to manually remove the "total" field, or script it away.)

Comment: Interesting that the file size seems to increase in no particular order or with no particular relationship

Comment: It looks like a pure linear increase from headers/dictionaries etc.

Comment: @Douglas: That was my expectation as well, but I've updated with many more files.  Apparently looks can be deceiving.

Comment: Note that gzip is a file format and not just a compressed data format like deflate; it’s just using deflate.

Answer (score 3):

Random data, or data encrypted with a good [cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) would probably be best.

But any good packer should only add constant overhead, once it decides that it can't compress the data. (@Frank). For a fixed overhead, an empty file, or a single character will give the greatest percentage overhead.

For packers that include the filename (e.g. rar, zip, tar), you could of course just make the filename **really** long :-)

Comment: Even if compressing adds only constant overhead, can a file grow unboundedly this way if, at every level, it does not compress? (I know this is purely theoretical :))

Comment: No. Random data, because it's random, is going to include some sequences that compress really, really well.

Comment: @DJClayworth but random data has none of the structure that compression requires, so the compressor will lose encoding the bits that aren't nice sequences.

Comment: @neworder yes each level of compression will almost certainly add a header, and compressed data can't be compressed any more.

Comment: The only way of avoiding the recursive overhead would be to declare that the 'foo' compressor detects it's trying to compress a 'foo' file, and just returns the original. The decompressor would, similarly, have to pass though non-foo files without modification. And there would be lots of problems with false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

Try to gzip the file that results from the following command:

```
echo a > file.txt
```

The compression of a 2 bytes file resulted of a 31 bytes gzipped file!

Answer (score 0):

A text file with 1 byte in it (for example one character like 'A') is stored in 1 byte on the disk but winrar rars it to 94 bytes and zips to 141 bytes.

I know it's a sort of cheat answer but it works.  I think it's going to be the biggest % difference between original size and 'compressed' size you are going to see.

Take a look at the formula for zipping, they are reasonably simple, and to make 'compressed' file larger than the original, the most basic way is to avoid any repeating data.

Answer (score 0):

All these compression algorithms are looking for redundant data. If you file has no or very less redundancy in it (like a sequence of `abac…az`, `bcbd…bz`, `cdce…cz`, etc.) it is very likely that the “deflated” output is rather an inflation.